# Подменю в Вордпресс, как поменять заголовок первого элемента

Tags: php, wordpress

В админке вордпресса хочу сделать подменю вида:

Email Campaigns

- Wait for approve
- Approved
- Sent
- Blacklist

  ```
  add_menu_page( 'Email Campaigns', 'Email Campaigns', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPage'),'dashicons-email-alt',4);
  add_submenu_page( 'email_campaigns', 'Approved', 'Approved', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns_approved', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPage'));
  add_submenu_page( 'email_campaigns', 'Sent', 'Sent', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns_sent', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPage'));
  add_submenu_page( 'email_campaigns', 'Blacklist', 'Blacklist', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns_blacklist', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPage'));
  ```

Получается, что первый элемент подменю назван именем главного меню:

[image: скриншот]

как изменить Email Campaigns в подменю на Wait for approve (в постах сделано значит можно!)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить аргумент $function в null и добавить подменю с новым заголовком.

```
    add_menu_page( 'Email Campaigns', 'Email Campaigns', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns', null,'dashicons-email-alt',4);
    add_submenu_page( 'email_campaigns', 'Wait for Approve', 'Wait for Approve', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPageWait'));
    add_submenu_page( 'email_campaigns', 'Approved', 'Approved', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns_approved', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPageApproved'));
    add_submenu_page( 'email_campaigns', 'Sent', 'Sent', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns_sent', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPageSent'));
    add_submenu_page( 'email_campaigns', 'Sent Error', 'Sent Error', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns_sent_error', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPageSentError'));
    add_submenu_page( 'email_campaigns', 'Blacklist', 'Blacklist', "manage_options", 'email_campaigns_blacklist', array(__CLASS__,'showEmailCampaignsPageBlacklist'));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]